# Keep Microsoft Word from adding files opened programmatically to its History

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I have a .NET program that opens a file programmatically in word to modify it.  Unfortunately, Microsoft word keeps the times the file was opened in word in its History, even though I don't want that to happen when the file is opened programmatically.

How can I keep this from happening in .NET?

Comment: And how and where are you processing the file?

Comment: Can you show the code opening / saving the document?

Comment: it was simply:  
`dim wordapp as new Word.Application()  
dim doc as word.Document=wordapp.open("tempfile.html")  
....  
doc.saveAs("endfile.doc")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Documents.Open` or `SaveAs` you can set the `AddToRecentFiles` property like this:

Open:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open("filename", AddToRecentFiles: false);
```

Save as:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("filename", AddToRecentFiles: false);
```

Comment: sounds good, but doesn't work like it should, in fact I still have both files in my history although I set the flag to false.

Comment: Ok it works like it should, I simply forgot to insert the flag to the .saveAs call as well.
Thanks for the help