# AddToRecentFiles does not work

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, registry, vsto

Some Time ago I asked a question on:

[Keep Microsoft Word from adding files opened programmatically to its History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059858/keep-microsoft-word-from-adding-files-opened-programmatically-to-its-history/23059917#23059917)

The answer to this, adding AddToRecentFiles:=False when opening and saving the file fixed the issue at that time.
Recently I recognized that the issue appeared again. The lines

```
 worddoc = wordap.Documents.Open("C:\Tools\Temp\" & tempExportFileName & ".html", AddToRecentFiles:=False)
```

and

```
 worddoc.SaveAs("C:\Tools\Out\" & tempExportFileName & ".html", FileFormat:=Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
```

Didn't changed at all from the time when it worked to now.
What do I need to do so that the files are, again, not added to the history?

---

Update:
Thanks to the answer of Eugene Astafiev my word it self does no longer display the .html files in its MRU-list. But if I right click the icon of word in the taskbar, all the .html files are there.
So how to fix this issue as well?

Comment: That previous question had a very good answer ;) . Are you sure you didn't open it by hand?

Comment: yes absolutely, the file is opened 3 Times with word (under different addresses and names) 2 times the "AddToRecentFiles:=False" is included, only the third time its not there, because THEN i want the path to be listed^^ the other two file version are only temporarly available, so there is no chance for me to open them by hand^^

Answer (score 1):

Office application keep the MRU (Most Recently Used) list in the windows registry. You can edit it programmatically.

See [How to clear the Most Recently Used list (MRU) list in Office programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313454) for more information.

Comment: I removed it there, but if I rightclick my word shortcut on the taskbar, the delete entrys are still there, although if I then click them word tells me "not found and wont work anymore"